# Image slider with link to separate pages in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to implement a image slider on sharepoint page.Image will be displayed and rotated after a certain time (say 5/10 secs).On click of those images I need to redirect user to a separate page.

I tried with Picture slider web part but how I link each images to specific URL?
I am not sure whether I need to store the path/URL in a list/lib corresponding each images.

any help/idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery plugin... http://galleria.io/

You can specify links to go along with images when you pass the gallery a datasource
http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/